# How to deny direct url access to files on Jetty

Tags: java, file, web-applications, jetty, block

I'm running webapps on Jetty. I have set "dirAllowed" to "false" to disable the directory browsing on the defined contextpath by 
webAppContext.setInitParameter("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.dirAllowed", "false").

But, users can still access other files (not located on the contextpath) through url (eg. http://somehost.yahoo.com:8081/abc.xml) and abc.xml is located under the root directory of the Jetty server.

Is there a way to block/deny direct url access to files located on Jetty? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not without adding some functionality to your webapp, there isn't.  A Java Webapp is essentially a standardized directory structure beginning at the context root (myWebApp in the sample below).

```
myWebApp/
    index.jsp
    styles/
        mywebapp.css
    images/
        myimage.png
    WEB-INF/
        web.xml
        lib/
            MyLib.jar
        classes/
            MyPackage/
                MyServlet.class
```

Anything above WEB-INF is directly serve-able, anything below WEB-INF isn't.  You could dream up some authorization scheme using Servlet Filters (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) and restrict access to content above WEB-INF.  Alternatively, if Authentication/Authorization is what you are after, look into Http Authorization and how it can be implemented in Jetty (http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-security-authentication.html).  One way or another, you are going to be some coding or configuration to restrict access to the content above WEB-INF in a Java webapp.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Bob! It seems that I can also access the file eg. web.xml under WEB-INF directly via url too (eg. http://host.com:8081/myWebApp/WEB-INF/web.xml). Is it because of the DefaultHandler? I'm not trying to do Authentication/Authorization but just try to find a way to restrict file access via url in Jetty. The files being accessed are located even above the myWebApp directory. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3934895 If you are accessing web.xml and the content below WEB-INF you haven't actually deployed a webapp and something is seriously wrong.  I suspect that you've put the contents of your WEB-APP compeletely in the root of Jetty's default web-app (if there is such a thing).  I think you need to stop, drop, and roll and read up on context descriptors in Jetty (http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-specific-webapp-deployment.html)